# Cannot Unlock Jenkins with initialAdminPassword

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, ibm-cloud

I have a setup of Jenkins on Ubuntu Server 18.04 on Hyper Protect Virtual Server in IBM Cloud. On the initial Unlock Jenkins page, I put my initialAdminPassword and then click Continue. I get a "Connection was reset" problem. What do you think are the causes of this.

I'm using openjdk-8-jdk if that matters.

[image]

[image]

Comment: try this to check the status of your port  "sudo ufw status"

Comment: yes 8080 is in the allowed ports

Comment: Are you using some kind of proxy, for example nginx? Are you using Docker?